# Code won't work when merging a javascript code in one function

Tags: javascript, php

Good day everyone!

I have a problem merging the codes in one function. (If it's possible).

First:

- There is a table.
- When the table row click two buttons will be enabled.

Here's the code:

```
   function enableRegButton() {
        $('#registerExist').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#edit').prop('disabled', false);

        // regButton execute when Enter key pressed
        $(document).unbind("keyup").keyup(function(e){ 
            var code = e.which; // recommended to use e.which, it's normalized across browsers
            if(code==13)
            {
                $("#registerExist").click();
            }
        });
    }
```

Second:

- When Escape key pressed it will disable all bind buttons.

Here's the code:

```
   $(document).keyup(function(e) {
         if (e.keyCode == 27) { // escape key maps to keycode `27`
            $('#registerExist').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#edit').prop('disabled', true);
            document.getElementById("enStudID").value = "";
            document.getElementById("enInfoID").value = "";
            document.getElementById("enCoffID").value = "";
            document.getElementById("enYearID").value = "";
        }
    });
```

Now, what I want to do are those two codes above will merge in one function and it will call the function and trigger all those codes so when I edit the code it will be centralized.

Here's my final code:

```
function enableRegButton() {
        $('#registerExist').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#edit').prop('disabled', false);

        // regButton execute when Enter key pressed
        $(document).unbind("keyup").keyup(function(e){ 
            var code = e.which; // recommended to use e.which, it's normalized across browsers

            settings();

        });
    }
// This code is for ESC button when pressed.
$(document).keyup(function(e) {

         settings();
    });

function settings(){
        if(code==13)
        {
            $("#registerExist").click();
        }
        else if (code==27){ // escape key maps to keycode `27`
            $('#registerExist').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#edit').prop('disabled', true);
            document.getElementById("enStudID").value = "";
            document.getElementById("enInfoID").value = "";
            document.getElementById("enCoffID").value = "";
            document.getElementById("enYearID").value = "";
        }
    }
```

Problem:

- Only the enable button is working when table row is click
- Pressing Escape key will not disable the enabled buttons.
- Code won't run when pressing Enter Key.

Comment: How many buttons do you have ? 2 by row, or globally two ? adding an html output example might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the key code to the `settings` method.

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    settings(e.keyCode);
});

function settings(code) {
```

Use the browser's developer console when debugging Javascript issues, it's an invaluable tool and picks up problems like this quite easily.

Comment: I'd recommend using `e.which` since they're already using jQuery, in order to avoid any cross-browser issues.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Daniel Bernsons it works! and also for Archer :-) btw off-topic I'm just confused with Javascript and JQuery differences when coding (lol) so I put the tag javascript.

Comment: @Daniel Bersons you mean the Inspect Element in chrome?

Comment: @Daniel Bersons oh! I see it... Thanks for that tip! Now it's easy to debugging javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the `code` variable in the unbind callback, not in the bind callback :)